# Dynamically iterate the same query against multiple tables using % in table name?

Tags: sql, select, vertica

I need to run this query on multiple tables in a Vertica DB:

```
select Distinct period_key from (
select item_key,period_key,store_key,salestype,event_description_key,count(*) from 
YYYYYY.DS_AA_FACT_ZZZZZZ_TABLE_NAME
group by item_key,period_key,store_key,salestype,event_description_key
having count(*) > 1
) a
```

I'm using YYYYYY and ZZZZZZ as placeholders in the above query.  Each YYYYYY database name has multiple tables with different ZZZZZZ names.  I'd like to be able to run one query and have it run this query on multiple tables that fit that pattern.

In a perfect world, this query would return 0 results. I'm checking for duplication (created by a bug that added a bunch of junk, I didn't do it.) So if it did have results, ideally after it iterated through all of the tables, the output would look something like database_name, tablename, period_key, count of records.

I can compromise on the YYYYYY part if I need to run it on each database seperately, but it's very tedious to find every table name manually that fits that pattern and change the table name each time.

I would even be OK with hardcoding these if I need to.  Although ideally I'd like it to be able to scale with finding any table name with %%%%%%.DS_AA_FACT_%%%%%%_TABLE_NAME

This is on a Vertica DB FYI.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Vertica, but it looks like they don't support dynamic SQL queries which will make this more challenging. You could use v_catalog.tables to get the list of tables to work from (WHERE table_name LIKE 'DS_AA_FACT_%_TABLE_NAME') and then script this out through some external language. See here for an example using bash: https://dwgeek.com/vertica-dynamic-sql-support-and-alternative.html/

Answer (score 0):

Try SQL generating SQL.

The generated query, in my case, won't work, as I don't have tables in my `dbadmin` schema that match the table structure you need. But it sort of conveys the idea.

Run `vsql`, Vertica's standard SQL command line tool. Use `\a` to not align the output. Use `\t` to output tuples only, no header , no footer. Redirect the output to a script called, for example `doit.sql` - using `\o doit.sql`, for example.

Of course, instead of my `LIMIT 2`, you would use a where condition on equality of `table_schema` and `ILIKE` of `table_name` with a pattern name you provide.

Finally, run `vsql -f doit.sql`.

In my demo here, I just output the initial query's output to screen.

```
\a
\t
SELECT 
  CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER w
    WHEN 1 THEN ''
    ELSE 'UNION ALL '
  END
||'SELECT DISTINCT period_key
FROM (
  SELECT 
     item_key
   , period_key
   , store_key
   , salestype
   , event_description_key
   , count(*)
   FROM '||table_schema||'.'||table_name||'
   GROUP BY item_key
   , period_key
   , store_key
   , salestype
   , event_description_key
   HAVING count(*) > 1
) a'
FROM v_catalog.tables
WHERE table_schema='dbadmin'
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY table_id)
LIMIT 2
;
-- out SELECT DISTINCT period_key
-- out FROM (
-- out   SELECT 
-- out      item_key
-- out    , period_key
-- out    , store_key
-- out    , salestype
-- out    , event_description_key
-- out    , count(*)
-- out    FROM dbadmin.this_is_the_new_table
-- out    GROUP BY item_key
-- out    , period_key
-- out    , store_key
-- out    , salestype
-- out    , event_description_key
-- out    HAVING count(*) > 1
-- out ) a
-- out UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT period_key
-- out FROM (
-- out   SELECT 
-- out      item_key
-- out    , period_key
-- out    , store_key
-- out    , salestype
-- out    , event_description_key
-- out    , count(*)
-- out    FROM dbadmin.people
-- out    GROUP BY item_key
-- out    , period_key
-- out    , store_key
-- out    , salestype
-- out    , event_description_key
-- out    HAVING count(*) > 1
-- out ) a
```